# How to set customised schedule in linux cron?

Tags: cron

I'm in need to set a cron in crontab like, a php file should be called according to the below schedule

> Mon-Fri, 9:00AM to 3:30 PM every one minute

I tried like below,

`*/1 * * * * wget http://example.com/trail.php`

Can someone help me how to create a cron for the above requirement?

Thanks,

Comment: Note that "a php file should be kick" is very ambiguous. In particular, it begets the question whether that or your crontab entry is your issue.

Comment: Updated the question, I have tried like,
{*/1 9-16 * * 1-5}. But still hitting every min.

Comment: "every one minute" is what you asked for, but now you don't like it?

Comment: every one minute should be on specified hours and days, this is what i needed.

Comment: ...and that's what the suggested solutions do. Maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Which of these three doesn't behave like you want? Also, how would you expect these to behave?

Comment: Nope.. not working, i believe first i has started with 9 O'Clock and second with every minute and finally ends with 3:30. But won't working anymore for each minute.

Comment: "not working" is not a description, it's a useless interpretation. Please, go and read the site guidelines, they explain how to ask smart questions, and you dearly need that info first.

Comment: It works like charm.
*/1 9-14 * * 1-5 wget http://example/alerts.php
0-30 15 * * 1-5 wget http://example/alerts.php

Answer (score 2):

Check the manpage of cron (`man 5 crontab`). You can do a lot of things, but there's no easy and simple way to achieve what you want. Probably the easiest is to use two entries:

```
*    9-14 * * * <command>
0-30 15   * * * <command>
```

Comment: I tried like */1 9-16 * * 1-5  after reading man-5-crontab. But still hitting every min again...

Comment: What about for every minute?

Comment: I don't understand the question in this last comment of yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following pattern and code

> ## Use the hash sign to prefix a comment
>
> ```
> # +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
> # |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
> # |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
> # |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
> # |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
> # |  |  |  |  |
> # *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
> #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

```
 */1 9-14 * * 1,2,3,4,5 wget http://example.com/trail.php
  0-30 15 * * 1,2,3,4,5 wget http://example.com/trail.php
```

Comment: May i know the purpose of 1,2,3,4,5. I didn't use it before.

Comment: */1 9-14 * * 1,5 wget http://example.com/alerts.php
0-30 15 * * 1,5 wget http://example.com/alerts.php

I configured like this, but again even after 6 PM it hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got the obsolete solution.

```
*/1 9-14 * * 1-5 wget -O /dev/null example/alerts.php
```

`0-30 15 * * 1-5 wget -O /dev/null example/alerts.php`

making this work like a charm.

Thanks for the answering, learnt from @Smit Raval and @Ulrich Eckhardt.